# Displaying loading image for a long time in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I want to know is there any technique through which I can control the time for which the loading image using jquery can be displayed for a long time. For example:

```
$('#ajax').html('<img src="ajax.gif"/>');
$('#iframe').load('file.php');
```

Now I want to know is there any way through which I can display the ajax.gif for a specified amount of time? Please let me know.

Comment: read `setTimeOut` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var loader = '<img id="loader" src="http://tools.patentcalls.com/images/spinner.gif"/>';
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout( function() {
        jQuery('#ajax').html(loader);
    }, 1000 );
    jQuery('#iframe').load('file.php');
});
```

Comment: @diEcho: where do I place the $('#iframe').load('file.php'); statement then? please can u edit the above code?

Comment: write the relative path of `file.php` was that working before??